# Encapsulation vs. inheritance, help making a choice

Tags: python, design-patterns, inheritance, abstract-class

I need to write handlers for several different case types (in Python). The interface for all this types are the same, but the handling logic is different.

One option would be defining a common class that receives the particular handler type as one of the  __init__ parameters:

```
class Handler:
   def __init__ (self, handlerType):
       self._handlerType = handlerType
       self._handler = handlerType.handleStuff

   def handleStuff(self, *args, **kwargs):
       return self._handler(args, kwargs)


# case specific handlers

class Handler_Case1:
   def handleStuff(self, *args, **kwargs):
       print 'Handling Case 1'


class Handler_Case2:
   def handleStuff(self, *args, **kwargs):
       print 'Handling Case 2'



if __name__ == '__main__':
   handlers = []
   handlers.append(Handler(Handler_Case1))
   handlers.append(Handler(Handler_Case2))
   for h in handlers:
       h.handleStuff()
```

However, this results in a TypeError:

> TypeError: unbound method handleStuff() must be called with Handler_Case1 instance as first argument (got tuple instance instead)

Another option is to mimic abstract function, as shown [here](http://norvig.com/python-iaq.html)("Q: Can you implement abstract classes in Python in 0 lines of code?"):

```
class Handler:
  def handleStuff(self, *args, **kwargs): abstract
  def commonFunction(self):
       print 'Common function'


 # case specific handlers

 class Handler_Case1(Handler):
  def handleStuff(self, *args, **kwargs):
      print 'Handling Case 1'


 class Handler_Case2(Handler):
  def handleStuff(self, *args, **kwargs):
      print 'Handling Case 2'



 if __name__ == '__main__':
  handlers = []
  h1 = (Handler_Case1())
  h2 = (Handler_Case2())
  handlers.append(h1)
  handlers.append(h2)
  for h in handlers:
      h.handleStuff()
      print
```

So, actually, I have two questions:

1. Which of the two approaches is more pythonic?
   and
2. How to implement the first one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I might be missing some subtle intricacy in your question, but given your first example, what precludes you from doing something like this:

```
class HandlerCase1(object):
    def handle_stuff(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print "Handling case 1"


class HandlerCase2(object):
    def handle_stuff(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print "Handling case 2"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    handlers = []
    handlers.append(HandlerCase1())
    handlers.append(HandlerCase2())
    for h in handlers:
        h.handle_stuff()
```

And if you want the classes to share some common (base) functionality, is there something keeping you from doing this:

```
class Handler(object):
    def common_function(self):
        print "Common function"


class HandlerCase1(Handler):
    def handle_stuff(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print "Handling case 1"


class HandlerCase2(Handler):
    def handle_stuff(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print "Handling case 2"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    handlers = []
    handlers.append(HandlerCase1())
    handlers.append(HandlerCase2())
    for h in handlers:
        h.handle_stuff()
        h.common_function()
```